# BigQuery print results in Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Query Update in BiqQuery on Python

*

```
def upd_data(QUERY):
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    z = query_job.result()
    print(query_job.state, query_job.result, query_job.query_results
```

*

I get on print - bound method QueryJob.query_results of google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob object at 0x000001CFDEC22748

I need - "N rows affected."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running DML queries and want to know how many rows were affected then try this instead (this is in client version `0.31` but should work from `0.28`):

```
query = """
  UPDATE table 
  SET col WHERE condition
"""

job = client.query(query)
result = job.result()
print("Total rows affected: ", job.num_dml_affected_rows)
```